# Deleting the opposite of what I want

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know where I am going wrong. I want this code to do NOTHING if both of these are true. I want it to delete the row if only the color is true. Please tell me what is wrong.

```
For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "E").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 _
        And InStr(1, Range("N" & lngRow), LCase("po box") > 0) Then
    Else:
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If


Next
```

I feel like I need another If statement or something? I have tried a bunch of different versions but I can't get it. Thank you for your help in advance.

I added this picture. If this explains it better. I need only the rows that are colored with PO Box. BUT also the rows that are not colored at all which would be most of them not pictured. (this is all fake info)

[image]

Comment: `And InStr(1, Range("N" & lngRow), LCase("po box") > 0)` should be `And InStr(1, Range("N" & lngRow), LCase("po box")) > 0`

Comment: You say in the question that you want it to do **nothing** if both are `True`, but a comment to an answer ("I need it to delete ONLY when the color is true but PO Box is not there.") makes it sound like you actually want it to do **something** when one is `True` and the other is `False`.  Please clarify.

Comment: After your edit, it sounds like you want to delete the rows that **are** coloured but **do not** contain "po box".  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah maybe I am not explaining it well. I need both of those things. I added a picture to my question that may explain it better. It should keep the rows with PO Box in Col D and keep the other rows that arent colored. It should only delete rows that are colored and DON"T have po box in them.

Comment: Yes. ARE colored with NO PO BOX need to be deleted : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete only the rows that are coloured but do not contain "po box" use

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "E").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 _
    And InStr(1, LCase(Range("N" & lngRow)), "po box") = 0 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Note: Your search for a `LCase` version of "po box" (which is already all lower case) within a string that wasn't all in lower case would also have given you problems.  You should check for "po box" within a `LCase` version of the cell.

Comment: YAYYYY IT WORKS! THANK YOU!

Comment: AH I didn't see your note about LCase until after I asked you about it. I deleted that part of my comment.

Comment: @Robillard I may not have added the note about LCase until after you asked it.  (Although I didn't see your comment, as soon as I finished posting the answer I thought "oops, I had better flag why I made that change", so I very quickly edited the answer.  And the edit was within the "grace period" so it doesn't actually show as an "edit" as far as the history goes.)

Comment: haha ok Yeah I didn't think I saw it before I commented : P anyway it works great. I don't have to filter anymore. I can use it on my whole file. Before when I tried it deleted EVERYTHING that wasn't red and had po box haha. But it works great now thank you! I think it was the LCase and maybe just the > sign.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it might be the placement of parenthesis for `Instr`. Maybe it should be  `InStr(1, Range("N" & lngRow), LCase("po box")) > 0` ?
Also I would suggest using `If Not`:

```
If Not (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "E").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 & _
    And InStr(1, Range("N" & lngRow), LCase("po box")) > 0) Then 'check your parenthesis here
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: you do not want the `&` or it will create a string `TRUETRUE`  Just the `_`

Comment: @ScottCraner you mean the & in the range?

Comment: no at the end of you first line in the If you have `& _` remove the `&`

Comment: @victorK Ah yeah I think he slipped that in there. Also, Victor if you see this, I like how that works I think but I also need it to not delete if neither are true. I need it to delete ONLY when the color is true but PO Box is not there. I think that code will delete everything that isn't colored as well. Which would be most of my records.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a two column .AutoFilter would be more appropriate.

```
Dim lngRows  As Long
lngRows = 6

With Worksheets("sheet4")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("E1:N" & lngRows)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 153, 204), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>*po box*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(.Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually found an answer where I don't have to autofilter. Before I worked this out that is how I was basically doing it. But I realized that my code wasn't taking the color into account so it was really only half working. I wanted to figure it out so I wouldn't need to autofilter and so it would work correctly in the first place.